# getting modified value in vaadin combobox with button click

Tags: button, combobox, vaadin7

I have a Vaadin ComboBox, populated with some values. I want to add a new value and pass that new value to the action listener upon clicking a Button, just next to the ComboBox.

I am not getting any clue how to proceed further.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445423/how-to-retrieve-the-newly-added-item-to-vaadin-combobox-with-a-button-click